# Update child component when state in parent component changes

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component which has the Hierarchy component inside it. The parent component is rendered conditionally based on the value of a variable `newform` in the state

```
    getFormRendererIO = () => {
        return (
            <div className="form-renderer-div">
                {this.state.showHierarchy ? (
                    <div className="form-renderer-div-hierarchy">
                        <Hierarchy
                            processName={this.props.processName}
                            // treeItems={HierarchyData}
                            body={this.props.body}
                            treeItems={this.state.hierarchyData}
                            openStartFormById={(e, id) => this.openStartFormById(e, id)} />
                    </div>
                ) : (
                        <div></div>
                    )}
                <div
                    className={this.state.showHierarchy ?
                        'form-renderer-div-renderer'
                        : 'form-renderer-div-renderer-without-hierarchy'}>
                    {
                        !this.state.showHierarchy ?
                            (
                                <div>
                                    <span>
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                                            icon={faLongArrowAltLeft}
                                            onClick={this.openLandingPage}
                                            className='backIcon'
                                            title='Back'
                                        />
                                        {/* <Button
                                            className='other-button'
                                            onClick={this.openLandingPage}>
                                            Back</Button> */}
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            ) : (<div></div>)
                    }
                    <div>
                        <FormRendererIO
                            processInstanceId={this.props.processInstanceId}
                            body={this.state.formJson}
                            secondForm={this.props.secondForm}
                            completedTask={this.state.completedTask}
                            key={this.props.index}></FormRendererIO>
                        {
                            this.state.showHierarchy ? (
                                <span>
                                    <Button
                                        className='other-button'
                                        onClick={this.openNewForm}>
                                        New</Button>
                                    {/* <FontAwesomeIcon
                                icon={faPlus}
                                onClick={this.openNewForm}
                                className='plusIcon'
                                title='New' /> */}
                                </span>
                            ) : (<div></div>)
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

render() {
        return (
            <>
                {
                    this.state.newForm ? this.getFormRendererIO() : this.getLandingPage()
                }
            </>
        );
    }
```

Below is the Hierarchy component

```
class Hierarchy extends Component {

    state = {
        hierarchyData: []
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    getTreeItemsFromData = (treeItems, index) => {
        // var hierarchyDataStr = localStorage.getItem("hierarchyData");
        // console.log(hierarchyDataStr ? JSON.parse(hierarchyDataStr) : 'NULL');
        console.log(treeItems);
        if (treeItems.length > 0) {
            return treeItems.map((treeItemData) => {
                let children = undefined;

                if (treeItemData.children && treeItemData.children.length > 0) {
                    children = this.getTreeItemsFromData(treeItemData.children);
                }

                return (
                    <SidebarLink>
                        <StyledTreeItem
                            key={treeItemData.parent}
                            nodeId={treeItemData.parent}
                            label={treeItemData.parent === 'root' ? '' : treeItemData.parent}
                            children={children}
                            // onClick={() => handleClick(treeItemData.id)}
                            onClick={(e) => this.props.openStartFormById(e, treeItemData)}
                        />
                    </SidebarLink>
                );
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TreeView
                // className={this.classes.root}
                defaultExpanded={["1"]}
                defaultCollapseIcon={<MinusSquare />}
                defaultExpandIcon={<PlusSquare />}
                defaultEndIcon={<CloseSquare />}
            >
                {this.getTreeItemsFromData(this.props.treeItems)}
            </TreeView>
        )
    };
}

export default Hierarchy;
```

I have an API inside the Parent `componentDidMount()` which updates the state of `hierarchyData` which is eventually passed as props in Hierarchy.

Below is the method calling the API

```
async getHierarchyFromAPI() {
        var formIOString = this.props.body.formIoString;
        var parentId = 'parent';
        var childId = 'child';
        var decisionId = 'decision';
        console.log(formIOString);
        if (formIOString) {
            var formIOJSON = JSON.parse(formIOString);
            var formComponents = formIOJSON.components;
            console.log(formComponents);
            for (var i = 0; i < formComponents.length; i++) {
                console.log(formComponents[i]["description"]);
                if (formComponents[i]["key"] === 'parent') {
                    parentId = this.getElementId(formComponents[i]);
                    parentId = formComponents[i]["key"];
                }
                if (formComponents[i]["name"] === 'child') {
                    childId = this.getElementId(formComponents[i]);
                    childId = formComponents[i]["name"];
                }
                if (formComponents[i]["key"] === 'decision') {
                    decisionId = formComponents[i]["key"];
                }
            }
        }

        const requestOptions = {
            method: "GET",
            credentials: "include",
        };

        let data = await fetch(localStorage.getItem("apiURL") +
            '/GRCNextBPMN/getHeirarchyData?processKey=' + this.props.processName.replace(/\s+/g, "")
            + '&parent=' + parentId
            + '&child=name' //+  childId
            + '&decisionId=' + decisionId
            + '&decisionValue=Approved',
            requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
        this.setState({ hierarchyData: data });
    }
```

The problem that I' am facing is that the API call is async and by the time the `hierarchyData` is updated the `Hierarchy` component is already rendered and the it shows as blank.

I want the hierarchyData to be updated in the `Hierarchy` component once the API call is finished and the component should be rendered. Please suggest a possible solution to resolve the issue

Added the `componentDidMount` method

```
componentDidMount() {
        if (this.landingPages.includes(this.props.processName)) {
            const requestOptions = {
                method: "GET",
                credentials: "include",
            };
            fetch(localStorage.getItem("apiURL") +
                '/GRCNextBPMN/getGridCols/' +
                this.props.processName.replace(/\s+/g, ""),
                requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(results => {
                    this.setState({
                        gridCols: results,
                        newForm: false,
                        showHierarchy: false
                    });
                })
        } else {
            this.getHierarchyFromAPI();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A prop change in the child component should force a rerender. Can you verify with some `console.log`s that you're updating and sending the updated prop down to `Hierarchy`?

Comment: @AdamStox Yes I already have that in the `getTreeItemsFromData`. It does print the updated props

Comment: This likely has to do with how you're updating state.hierarchyData in the parent.
Can you show the code where that's being done?
(I saw the code for "getHierarchyFromAPI()", but what's calling it?)

Comment: @MerkleGroot `getHierarchyFromAPI()` is being called in the `componentDidMount` method

Comment: Can you please paste the full componentDidMount() method? My guess is that the issue is in there, but I can't be certain without seeing it.

Comment: Added the code for `componentDidMount`